# Multicolor line , values from a .txt folder, how to do it? MATLAB

Tags: matlab

One solution to plot a multicolor line is to plot separately the values of the abscisses in n sets and for the n sets to set different colors.

I have an idea how to,  for a fixed value N,  plot the function, but my problem is that I don't have a function to plot. I take my values inside a .txt folder and I don't know how to cut the values.

My aim is to cut even-handedly the set of values, taking into account that I don't know how many values there gonna be.

For now I have this :

```
data = readtable('test.txt');
figure('Name','Phase'  , 'units','normalized','outerposition',[(8/100) (0.3- 16/100) 0.5 0.7]);
hold on
   plot(data{:,2},data{:,3}, 'k.', 'LineWidth',1.5 );
   plot(data{:,4},data{:,5}, 'r.', 'LineWidth',1.5  );
xL = xlim;
yL = ylim;
line([0 0], yL);  %x-axis
line(xL, [0 0]);  %y-axis   
      title(['Phase portrait'])
      xlabel('f')
      ylabel('f '' ')
hold off
```

I read the values of the function in a .txt file, and then I plot the 2nd/3rd columns and 4/5th columns. The first column is the time evoluating.

any idea?

[image: the first column is the time, and then by pair of two, you have the x_axis and y-axis]

The first column is the time, and then by pair of two, you have the x_axis and y-axis

Comment: Could you possible provide a snippet of `test.txt` file?

Comment: idk what a snippet is but i ll add a screen right now

Comment: Cheers, so the problem is the that you don't know the size of the .txt file beforehand and you want to ensure that every entry in your graph has a different color?

Comment: Not exactly. I know that there is going to be either 3 collums or 5. I want that one part of the line is e.g. Plotted in red, next in green, next in blue. For instance, that is the same as plotting the sinus in red for x between 0 and pi, then in gree for x between pi and 2pi etc... The problem is that I don't know how many values there are going to be in the .txt

Comment: Right. The way you are plotting the data right now, the entries are just points in the graph. Do you simply want to ensure that the points in the graphs have different colours, or do you want to draw a line passing between the two points for each entry in your txt file, and have said line split in two different colors?

Comment: The best would be that the points change color continuosly, depending of the time (if its the first point it is in one color, and if it s the last point it is in another color). Said that, if you keep the points or you create a line is for me the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code reads the data from the .txt file and determines how many entries there are. *n* is used for the number of entries, *c* is used for the number of columns. Since you indicated that the fifth column may not always be present in the .txt file, a conditional statement is used to check for the number of columns.

A for loop is used to plot the entries on the same graph.
The different colors are obtained by setting the RGB triplet in the plot function to random values with **rand** function.

```
data = readtable('file.txt');
n = numel(data.Var1);
c = size(data,2);

figure('Name','Phase'  , 'units','normalized','outerposition',[(8/100) (0.3- 16/100) 0.5 0.7]);
for i=1:n
    plot(data{i,2},data{i,3},'.','Color',rand(3,1),'MarkerSize',10);  
    hold on
    if c>=5
        plot(data{i,4},data{i,5},'.','Color',rand(3,1),'MarkerSize',10);
    end
end
xL = xlim;
yL = ylim;
line([0 0], yL);  %x-axis
line(xL, [0 0]);  %y-axis   
title(['Phase portrait'])
xlabel('f')
ylabel('f '' ')
hold off
```

For the first few entries of your .txt file, the graph will look like this:

[image]

I made the marker size slightly bigger to enable you to clearly distinguish the different colors between the points. You can adjust that by changing the **MarkerSize**.

Comment: that is so good. Thank you very much !!!!! I ve made minor changes, but it really does saves me. I have set for the color :     [1 (1-i/n) 0] ; [0 (i/n) (1-i/n)]

Comment: You are welcome. Yes that makes sense, I was not sure whether you wanted random or pseudo-random values for the colors. Glad it helped!